# How to create controller inside a controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a controller inside a controller in angular Js. But my code is not working. Please help me on this.

Controller :

```
app.controller('MainController',function($rootScope,$scope){
    console.log('MainController Created');
    $scope.test = "Success";

    app.controller('InnerController',function($scope){
        console.log('Inside the InnerController');
        console.log($scope.test);
    })
});
```

below is my html body:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
        Enter your Name :
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="your name">
        <div ng-show="name">
            <h2>This is called Two way binding :: {{name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="InnerController">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can't create nested controller like this... But you can inject one into another.

Comment: Could you please kindly help me with a code snippet to inject a controller in another controller @SankarRaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a controller inside another controller. But you can nest DOM elements with different controllers inside each other. So you should change your controllers' declaration to this:

```
app.controller('MainController',function($rootScope,$scope){
    console.log('MainController Created');
    $scope.test = "Success";
});

app.controller('InnerController',function($scope){
    console.log('Inside the InnerController');
    console.log($scope.test);
});
```

Pay attention that `test` is still available in the `InnerController`.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your inner controller declaration outside of MainController, because they both need to be initialised before html is parsed

```
app.controller('MainController',function($rootScope,$scope){
    console.log('MainController Created');
    $scope.test = "Success";
});

app.controller('InnerController',function($scope){
    console.log('Inside the InnerController');
    console.log($scope.test);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in html like you did main is a father controller of innercontroller
but in angular it is controller with himself like that:

```
app.controller('MainController',function($rootScope,$scope){
    console.log('MainController Created');
    $scope.test = "Success";
});


 app.controller('InnerController',function($scope){
       console.log('Inside the InnerController');
       console.laog($scope.test);
   })
```